# Remove items from collection if item is not found in other collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections, let's say `cars` and `owners`. One `owner` has many `cars`. And `one car` belongs to only `one owner`. When owner dies, I need to delete all cars from `cars` collection. In order to do it I created script file in js. The `aliveOwners` is `undefined`, what is the best way to do it? Is it possible to make it using `Mongoose`?

```
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    var aliveOwners = db.collection('owner').find({}); // TODO. it should get only owner ids
    console.log(aliveOwners); // undefined, mb cuz of non blocking
    db.collection('cars').remove({ ownerId: { $nin: aliveOwners } })); //TODO. delete cars if owner id does not exist in aliveOwners
});
```

Comment: Why would you not simply embed the details for the cars within the owner at the first place? This should be one of the reasons you are using MongoDB, and if you are just going to treat it like an RDBMS then there is little point. No way possible are you going to breach 16MB on owned cars ever. Not even if you are Jay Leno

Answer (score 0):

The **find** method is asynchronous which is why **aliveOwners** is undefined.

You'll need to pass a callback function which receives the found documents and continue your code there:

```
db.collection('owner').find({}, function(err, aliveOwners) {
    console.log(aliveOwners);

    // Continue code
});
```

NOTE: As a car belongs to only one owner, it might be best to include them as sub-documents in the owner documents.

Comment: What if I have many related models, owner-> cars -> wheels.
`db.collection('owner').find({}, function(err, aliveOwners) {
    console.log(aliveOwners);
db.collection('cars').find({}, function(err, allCars) {
    // Continue code
   // same for wheels.
});
});`. While it creates many nested callbacks. what is the best way to handle situations like this? BTW when should i close db connection?

Comment: You could use promises instead of callbacks.